# How to open file programmatically using EnvDTE in C#

Tags: c#, add-in, visual-studio-extensions

How to open file programmatically using EnvDTE in C#.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you have a hook to the correct DTE instance...

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenFile", "c:\\derp.txt");
```

Comment: surround the path with double quotes if it has spaces

Comment: @IvanFerrerVilla's comment fixed (what seemed like an ambiguous) error about "/" is an invalid command that I was getting from VS when running the command because of spaces in the path.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following snippet directly in the Visual Studio Console:

```
$DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile("c:\derp.txt",$DTE.Constants.vsViewKindTextView)
```

It should open the file as long as it exists...