# VS2013 Extension: How to open a file?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I would like to create a VS2013 Browser Link extension that opens a basic javascript file. How do I invoke VS's methods to open a javascript file?  I'm new at this and the API to do this in a traditional VS extension looks very hairy and scary!

Comment: Can you be [much] more detailed about what you are hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Basically I have a Single Page Application with lots of modules. In debug mode, I want to show a tooltip on each user module. This tool tip will have a link such that when the user clicks on it, VS will open the JS source code that rendered that module. I can provide the proprietary logic that maps the link in the tooltip to a JS file in a VS project. I just need to know how to open a JS file when the user clicks on a link.

Comment: I just found the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039226/how-to-open-file-programmatically-using-envdte-in-c-sharp